# 401 - Token invalid when requesting video feed

Tags: youtube-api

I'm at a loss for what's wrong. I'm always getting `com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: Token invalid Token invalid` when making API requests.

I have the following flow:

1. link user account
2. use credentials to get video upload entries

The code I use to link the user (get permission for my application) uses the `JdoDataStoreFactory` to persist user tokens and refresh info between API calls.

I used the following scopes when I ask the user to authorize my apps:

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload`
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`

Using `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` I do a `loadCredentials` passing in the userId from my application that I used when requesting their auth token.  I then feed those credentials to `YouTubeService`'s `getFeed` method, requesting the url for video feeds: `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads`

It looks like this:

```
service.setOAuth2Credentials(credentials)
videoFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(USER_FEED_PREFIX + DEFAULT_USER
        + UPLOADS_FEED_SUFFIX), VideoFeed.class)
```

After this executes, I always get the stacktrace:

> com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService$SessionExpiredException: Token
>   invalid   Token invalid
>
> ## Token invalid
>
> ### Error
>   401
>
> at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:570)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
>     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)   at
>   com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
>     at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)

The way I'm initiating my request to my service is via curl, my command looks like this:

`curl http://localhost:8080/user/someUserId/content`

Using Wireshark I see the following in my request:

```
GET /feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1                                                                                   
Authorization: Bearer <the_auth_token_for_the_user>
User-Agent: MyApp YouTube-Java/1.0 GData-Java/null(gzip)
X-GData-Client: MyApp
Accept-Encoding: gzip
GData-Version: 2.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Connection: keep-alive
```

I'm stuck.

Comment: SessionExpiredException: it looks like you're having troubles logging in

Comment: @BlackBear login is working great and the authtokens are indeed being persisted and subsequently retrieved when I'm calling `loadCredentials` so I'm not sure what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  I was trying to query the user's uploaded videos, and apparently for an app to do that it has to be authorized for the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube` scope, not the scopes I had configured